# systemd.time - OnCalendar= unwanted running after suspend

Tags: systemd-timer, systemd-unit

I wanted a "more stupid" version of crontab: Run only on given times, don't catch up after suspension.
I.e. when a service should have been triggered by crontab, but the machine was suspended, it was triggered right after resuming. That's what I didnt' want.

I solved this by writing a systemd.timer unit (instead of crontab) and accordingly a -sleep.service, which deactivated the timer unit, when the machine is going to suspend and reactivated the timer unit when the system resumed. Since my last update last weekend suddenly it behaved like crontab did: the timer unit started it's target, just when the timer unit got started, even though it wasn't a given time within the timer unit.

I checked the logs and the -sleep.service unit did it's job and deactivated the timer unit. (Also the timer unit is showing it's de- and reactivation.)
However, as I said:
I don't want the timer unit to "catch up". I want it ONLY triggering it's unit on given times, never else!

Thank you very much!

Regards
Dom

```
# horcrux-sleep.service
[Unit]                                                           
Description=horcrux sleep hook                                   
Before=sleep.target                                              
Before=shutdown.target                                           
StopWhenUnneeded=yes                                             
RefuseManualStart=yes                                            
                                                                 
[Service]                                                        
Type=oneshot                                                     
RemainAfterExit=yes                                              
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl stop horcrux.timer                  
ExecStop=/usr/bin/systemctl start horcrux.timer                  
                                                                 
[Install]                                                        
WantedBy=sleep.target                                            
Also=horcrux.timer
```

```
# horcrux.timer
Jun 27 06:51:15 citadel systemd[1]: Stopped Schedule for backup.
[Unit]                                                           
Description=Schedule                       
                                                                 
[Timer]                                                          
OnCalendar=Mon *-*-* 20..21:00:00                                                                                                 

OnCalendar=Tue..Thu *-*-* 17..21:00:00                           
OnCalendar=Fri *-*-* 17..23:00:00                                                                                                 

OnCalendar=Sat *-*-* *:00:00                                     
OnCalendar=Sun *-*-* 00..21:00:00                                
                                                                 
## Spätschicht                                                   
#OnCalendar=Mon..Wed,Fri *-*-* 7..11:00:00                       
                                                                 
## Frühschicht am Donnerstag                                     
#OnCalendar=Thu *-*-* 13..16:00:00                               
                                                                 
## Frühschicht täglich                                           
#OnCalendar=Mon..Fri *-*-* 7..11:00:00                           
                                                                 
## freie Tage                                                    
#OnCalendar=Mon..Fri 9..11,14..16,0..5:00:00                     
                                                                 
## Urlaub / Krankheit                                            
#OnCalendar=*-*-* *:00:00                                        
                                                                 
                                                                 
Persistent=1                                                     
                                                                 
AccuracySec=1sec                                                 
                                                                 
[Install]                                                        
WantedBy=timers.target                                           
Also=horcrux-sleep.service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests, also `Persistent=boolean` didn't do the job. So far, I totally forgot about `/etc/crontab` and all times used `crontab -e` just to get the problems with anachron which leaded to the systemd configuration you see above and therefore this thread at all.

<s>But adding the job to `/etc/crontab` does the job without anachron - without "catching up".</s>

All details for proper setup of `/etc/crontab` can be found within crontab manual.

---

**The real issue: Difference between hardware clock and system clock.**
Solution: Setting the Linux' system time to UTC via `timedatectl set-local-rtc 0`

In Detail:
The system is dual boot *Linux* and *Windows*.
Once I set up this system it were *Arch Linux* and *Windows 7*. Now it is *Manjaro Linux* and *Windows 10*. While *Arch* was in charge, the hardware clock was set to UTC within *Windows*, so it fits *Linux*.
But somehow, when I installed *Manjaro*, the *Linux*' system clock was set to local time (TZ).
So while *Windows* kept it's registry key and used UTC *Linux* started using TZ - and on every boot and resume the time jump caused by *ntp* triggered the service.
After some time testing I was able to verify. One still needs `/etc/crontab` to omit the catch up but also `/etc/crontab` is not enough, when time switches trigger. This also executes `/etc/crontab/`-entries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe persistent interferes.
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#Persistent=

Set Persistent=false

Comment: I changed to persistent=false, but every time the timer gets activated on resume (from suspend) the job is ran. → Problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to deactivate and reactivate while suspending/resuming when you use `Persistent=true`.
Because that's the whole idea of that directive, it stores info on disk for re-use.

So maybe the problem you are facing is due to the usage of your `horcrux-sleep.service` which should not be needed with systemd timers.

You should maybe check the value of `RandomizedDelaySec=` of the timer unit using `systemctl show` to see if it has a non zero value, in which case you could set it to `0`.
Plus values of `OnClockChange=`, `OnTimezoneChange=` and `RemainAfterElapse=`

*(See `man systemd.timer` for explanation of these directives)*

Comment: `Persistent=true` is exactly what I NOT want. According to the manual it triggers a catch up for the unit if the timer would have triggered the unit while the timer was off.
Please help me if I understood it wrong or if I don't get what's in your mind.

Comment: Then maybe you need to report at: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues

Comment: @DomX, did you read the description of the `systemctl clean` command? Maybe you need to use that when your machine returns from suspending...